# error.code 139 when running exec in node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm using node.js to execute an external file (compiled cpp). If I execute the file on it's own, the program works ok. I should get the following output:

> Got response 534, round-trip delay: 9569

I would like to use websokets to take the value and display on a webpage. Unfortunately, when running the program from node.js I have the following output:

> stdout: stderr: exec error: null
>   I don't understand what is happening and why if I run the application from command line I get the desired output?

Thank you and please forgive me for the dumb question!

After changing the way I execute the file I get the following output:

> stdout: stderr: exec error: **139**

the changes I have made are:

```
exec('sudo /home/pi/gitwork/RF24/RPi/RF24/examples/light -m 1',
                      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                                     socket.emit("response");
                                     console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                                     console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                            if (error !== null) {
                                  console.log('exec error: ' + error.code);
                            }
```

server.js

```
function sendMessage(socket){
        console.log("execute app");
        exec.execFile('/home/pi/gitwork/RF24/RPi/RF24/examples/light',
                      ['-m', 1],
                        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                                 socket.emit("response");
                                 console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                                 console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                        if (error !== null) {
                              console.log('exec error: ' + error.code);
                        }

              });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('get', function (data) {
              console.log("get received");
              sendMessage(socket);

      });
});
```

light.cpp

```
bool switchLight(int action){
        radio.startListening();
        bool timeout = false;
        while ( ! radio.available() ) {
                sleep(10);
        }

        if (radio.available()){
                unsigned long got_time=0;
                radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );
                printf("Got response %lu, round-trip delay: %lu\n\r",got_time,millis()-got_time);
                return true;
        }else{
                printf("Failed, response timed out.\n\r");
                return false;
                }
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv){

        char choice;
        setup();
        bool switched = false;
        int counter = 0;

        while(( choice = getopt( argc, argv, "m:")) != -1){

                if (choice == 'm'){

                    printf("\nOpening the gates...\n");
                    while(switched == false && counter < 5){
//                      switched = true;
                        switched = switchLight(atoi(optarg));
                        counter ++;
                    }

                }else{
                    // A little help:
                        return 4;
                        printf("\n\rIt's time to make some choices...\n");
                }

            //return 0 if everything went good, 2 otherwise
             if (counter < 5 )
//              printf("ok ok ok");
                 return 0;
             else
                 return 2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I comment below line, the script works ok. The example I'm trying to use is this one: http://hack.lenotta.com/arduino-raspberry-pi-switching-light-with-nrf24l01/

This made me to check the differences of RF24 libraries (the one I use and the one used in the example) and it seems that they are using a different library. I'll try to change it and see what it happens.

```
radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) );
```